# Extracting pokemon card borders using image processing

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I've got a dataset of Pokemon cards, and I want to do borders grading. To do the borders grading, I want to extract the pokemon card borders when an image is given. I'm attaching sample image of borders and pokemon card below.[image: This image is of a pokemon card]

[image: The first second image is of borders of a pokemon card]

What I've tried for extracting borders,
1: applied multiple edge detection algos and canny almost worked the best.
2: tried extracting contours and working on it, but contours do not work nicely if the image isn't of good quality.
3: tried applying kmeans for images but it fails when the borders and the card itself have the same colors.
4: training a machine learning model for grading a border after extracting somewhat of border using the kmeans method.
Need help...

Comment: any assumptions possible, like that that border is in the outer 50% of the image regions?

Comment: yes, you can assume that, since I'm preprocessing the images and only the card exists after that. I'm removing background by myself, so borders should be in the outer 50% of the image.

Comment: Detect the yellow pixels.

Comment: cannot do that,this is just 1 image, a card can have any color border, also, many cards have yellow color in the card, so cannot do that, i specifically need only borders.

Comment: First, preprocessing your images help a lot with image processing algorithms. Then I think segmentation is your answer. After that you can use morphology to remove other parts of the image and make a mask from the border. Applying the mask to the original image gives you the original border alone. Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: @ZainabRostami I've actually tried the pipeline you are talking about. It may be I applied wrong processes, but I've tried it. For the image segmentation part, I've used kmeans and I'm trying to segment based on colors, but a lot of time, the card's border are of same color as the card, so it doesn't segment the border. I've tried preprocessing as in shining the card, finding edges, removing weak edges, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use segmentation based on colors. There are other types of segmentation you can check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/image-segmentation-using-pythons-scikit-image-module). Test to see which one fits your need.

Comment: Are the cards always mostly axis aligned to the image axes?

Comment: @Micka nopes, they are not axis aligned...